# Does the data your fetching with getStaticProps in Next.js have to be an array of objects?

Tags: next.js

I am new to next.js and am fooling around with their custom hooks like getStaticProps()and I noticed that in every example and every time I try and fetch data unless it's an array of objects throws an error.

For example, if I try to fetch a single JSON object from the kanye.rest api it throws an error when I try to access the data and says in must be serialized JSON but I am calling the .json() method on the data.

Can anyone help me out here.

```
const index = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{props.data}</h1>
        </div>
    );
};

export default index;

export async function getStaticProps() {
    const res = await fetch('https://api.kanye.rest')
    const data = await res.json()

    return {
        props: {
            data,
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The data doesn't have to be an array. Can you post the full error you're seeing?

Answer (score 0):

Your code and api are working. I got the result and passed it to client successfully.

[image]

`undefined` cannot be serialized in javascript. So if you get that warning, that means you are getting something unserializable

You cannot render object as react child: it should be

```
      {data.quote}
```

React does not know what to do with objects

Comment: yes correct it is fetching the data fine now, its just when I try and render it in the h1 tag it throws an error.

Comment: all the examples I have seen grab an array and then map it. but I only have a single item so I dont need to do that.

Comment: this is the error I get...... Server Error

Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {quote}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working now guys, when I was trying to render the data in the h1 tag I had a syntax error I was trying to access it with {props.data} instead of {props.data.quote} and to make it easier I just passed in { data } de-structured into the function and accessed the quote with {data.quote}

Sorry for being stupid guys, Sometimes you cant see errors in your own code.